# Save Record Index to Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to save the index of each record in a table to that record's index column.  So let's say I sorted my records:

```
select * from Users order by DateTimeCreated
```

Now, let's say I wanted to cache their positions in this sorting.  I would like to do something like this:

```
update Users set SortedIndex=GETINDEX() order by DateTimeCreated
```

How can I do something like this?  I could code it in C#, but I'd prefer a more efficient way than looping and setting each record individually.  I need this number pre-determined (written on each record) rather than determined at runtime.  Thank you.

Comment: How will you maintain the number correct in the presence of delete, insert and update operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
update users set SortedIndex=row from
(
  select userid, row_number() over(order by DateTimeCreated desc) as row from users 
) u
where users.userid = u.userid
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked, but does anyone else agree that this is the most performant method to accomplish the task?

Comment: OK, I guess this is it.  Thank you, codingbiz!